# Number of business days dynamic month

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to make a report in Access about how many overtime every employee has. Because some workes work from Mo-Th 10h and Fr 0h i cant say

> Count everything above 8h .

Therefore I need all business days a month * 8h and  compare it with actual working time which I Sum by month ( already working! )

Solution approach:

```
 SELECT Format([TaetigkeitsDatum],"mmmm yy") AS Monat,  
 tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsPersonalID,  
 Sum(tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsStundenAnzeigen) AS  SummevonTaetigkeitsStundenAnzeigen
 FROM tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung
 GROUP BY Format([TaetigkeitsDatum],"mmmm yy"),  
 tbl_Taetigkeitserfassung.TaetigkeitsPersonalID;
```

This shows me the formatted Month(TaetigkeitsDatum), the Employee(TaetigkeitsPersonalID) and the Sum of the Working Hours ( TaetigkeitsStundenAnzeigen).

But I dont know how to display the hours of Business days that month so I can compare and display overtime...

Expected Solution:

January 19: 23Days (without Weekend, holidays dont matter) * 8h = 184h
Working Time of Mr.X = 186h   -> 2h Overtime

DateDiff isnt working, because I need 2 Dates for it to work and than there is the "only count business days" problem.

Comment: Take a look at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/date-time/find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates.  Access doesn't have a defined function for this but there are many solutions-quite a few on stackoverflow itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
WorkDays: ISO_WorkdayDiff(DateSerial(Year([TaetigkeitsDatum]), Month([TaetigkeitsDatum]), 1), DateSerial(Year([TaetigkeitsDatum]), Month([TaetigkeitsDatum]) + 1, 1))
```

and a function like this:

```
Public Function ISO_WorkdayDiff( _
  ByVal datDateFrom As Date, _
  ByVal datDateTo As Date, _
  Optional ByVal booExcludeHolidays As Boolean) _
  As Long

' Purpose: Calculate number of working days between dates datDateFrom and datDateTo.
' Assumes: 5 or 6 working days per week. Weekend is (Saturday and) Sunday.
' May be freely used and distributed.

' 1999-04-23. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, Copenhagen
' 2000-10-03. Constants added.
'             Option for 5 or 6 working days per week added.
' 2008-06-12. Option to exclude holidays from the count of workdays.

  Const cbytWorkdaysOfWeek  As Byte = 5
  ' Name of table with holidays.
  Const cstrTableHoliday    As String = "tblHoliday"
  ' Name of date field in holiday table.
  Const cstrFieldHoliday    As String = "HolidayDate"

  Dim bytSunday             As Byte
  Dim intWeekdayDateFrom    As Integer
  Dim intWeekdayDateTo      As Integer
  Dim lngDays               As Long
  Dim datDateTemp           As Date
  Dim strDateFrom           As String
  Dim strDateTo             As String
  Dim lngHolidays           As Long
  Dim strFilter             As String

  ' Reverse dates if these have been input reversed.
  If datDateFrom > datDateTo Then
    datDateTemp = datDateFrom
    datDateFrom = datDateTo
    datDateTo = datDateTemp
  End If

  ' Find ISO weekday for Sunday.
  bytSunday = Weekday(vbSunday, vbMonday)

  ' Find weekdays for the dates.
  intWeekdayDateFrom = Weekday(datDateFrom, vbMonday)
  intWeekdayDateTo = Weekday(datDateTo, vbMonday)

  ' Compensate weekdays' value for non-working days (weekends).
  intWeekdayDateFrom = intWeekdayDateFrom + (intWeekdayDateFrom = bytSunday)
  intWeekdayDateTo = intWeekdayDateTo + (intWeekdayDateTo = bytSunday)

  ' Calculate number of working days between the two weekdays, ignoring number of weeks.
  lngDays = intWeekdayDateTo - intWeekdayDateFrom - (cbytWorkdaysOfWeek * (intWeekdayDateTo < intWeekdayDateFrom))
  ' Add number of working days between the weeks of the two dates.
  lngDays = lngDays + (cbytWorkdaysOfWeek * DateDiff("w", datDateFrom, datDateTo, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays))

  If booExcludeHolidays And lngDays > 0 Then
    strDateFrom = Format(datDateFrom, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    strDateTo = Format(datDateTo, "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    strFilter = cstrFieldHoliday & " Between #" & strDateFrom & "# And #" & strDateTo & "# And Weekday(" & cstrFieldHoliday & ", 2) <= " & cbytWorkdaysOfWeek & ""
    lngHolidays = DCount("*", cstrTableHoliday, strFilter)
  End If

  ISO_WorkdayDiff = lngDays - lngHolidays

End Function
```